# How to re-order list elements in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a list in `Perl`.

```
@alist=("a_vld","a_sf","a_ef","a_val");
print join(',', @alist), "\n";
```

Output:

```
a_vld,a_sf,a_ef,a_val
```

How can I re-order the elements in list such that its output is as following expected output:

```
a_sf,a_ef,a_vld,a_val
```

Note: `a_` will keep changing with different strings but I want to preserve the order of `sf,ef,vld,val`

Comment: So you want a specific order determined by these particular strings, `sf,ef,vld,val`?

Comment: Yes @zdim, that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a short list, use a sort function that identifies the sequences in order

```
@sorted = sort {
    ($b =~ /sf$/) <=> ($a =~ /sf$/)
        || ($b =~ /ef$/) <=> ($a =~ /ef$/)
        || ($b =~ /vld$/) <=> ($a =~ /vld$/)
        || ($b =~ /val$/) <=> ($a =~ /val$/)
} @alist;
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to order (sort) by a given set is to associate a numeric order with its elements.

Then we need to find these keys in the strings in the list to sort.  That is done once, ahead of the actual sorting, via the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my @alist = ("a_vld", "a_sf", "a_ef", "a_val");

my @keys = qw(sf ef vld val);                       # keys to sort by
my %order_by = map { $keys[$_] => $_ } 0..$#keys;

my @sorted = 
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $order_by{$a->[1]} <=> $order_by{$b->[1]} }
    map {
        my $elem = $_;
        [ $elem, first { $elem =~ /$_/ } keys %order_by ]
    }
    @alist;

say "@sorted";
```

This prints the line:   `a_sf a_ef a_vld a_val`

The elements of the list are associated with the sorting keys by finding the key in the string via a regex. With this in mind the above can be used reasonably generally, with a desired list of keys .

Answer (score 3):

**If there's always a `_` before the code, and if the code is always at the end**

```
use Sort::Key qw( ikeysort );

my @order = qw( sf ef vld val );
my %order = map { $order[$_] => $_ } 0..$#order;

my @sorted = ikeysort { /_([^_\W]+)\z/ ? $order{$1} : 0 } @unsorted;
```

The above is a faster, cleaner version of the following:

```
my @order = qw( sf ef vld val );
my %order = map { $order[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#order;

my @sorted =
   sort {
      my $key_a = /_([^_\W]+)\z/ ? $order{$1} : 0;
      my $key_b = /_([^_\W]+)\z/ ? $order{$1} : 0;
      $key_a <=> $key_b || $a cmp $b
   }
      @unsorted;
```

**Otherwise**

```
use Sort::Key qw( ikeysort );

my @order = qw( sf ef vld val );
my %order = map { $order[$_] => $_ } 0..$#order;
my $alt = join '|', map quotemeta, @order;
my $re = qr/($alt)/;

my @sorted = ikeysort { /$re/ ? $order{$1} : 0 } @unsorted;
```

The above is a faster, cleaner version of the following:

```
my @order = qw( sf ef vld val );
my %order = map { $order[$_] => $_ } 0..$#order;
my $alt = join '|', map quotemeta, @order;
my $re = qr/($alt)/;

my @sorted =
   sort {
      my $key_a = /$re/ ? $order{$1} : 0;
      my $key_b = /$re/ ? $order{$1} : 0;
      $key_a <=> $key_b || $a cmp $b
   }
      @unsorted;
```

Comment: You were missing the declaration of `$re` in your first two versions; and the `$` before `alt` in the last two version; I took the liberty to edit that in. Hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: @Dada, Oops. I broke it in a refactor. Thanks for the attempt, but the top and bottom solutions were the same after your change. I have now finished the fix.

Comment: Oh indeed, I didn't pay too much attention when editing, and didn't noticed that both solutions became the same! Nice answer btw; I didn't know about Sort::Key :)

Comment: @Dada, With Sort::Key, you get the benefits of a ST or GRT without the messy code :) And it's not limited to simple keys as you might thing at a glance. For example, I don't handle ties in my S::K version, but I could have.